# Spring Boot Exit Code Generator - implementation does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy

I realize there have been a couple similar unsolved questions on this topic here on SO, however, I am including a [cloneable MCVE on GitHub](https://github.com/alessandroscarlatti/spring-exit-code-gen) so it will be easy to reproduce the problem scenario.

**Scenario**

I am trying to implement a Spring Boot exit code generator, per the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#exit-org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext-org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator...-).  It looks like Spring Boot is invoking the exit code generator, but the application exits with code 0, not the given exit code.  What am I missing?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@Slf4j
class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args)
    }

    @Override
    void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.exit(ctx, new ExitCodeGenerator() {
            @Override
            int getExitCode() {
                log.info 'retrieving exit code.'
                return -1
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\pc\IdeaProjects\spring-exit-code-gen>gradlew bootRepackage

C:\Users\pc\IdeaProjects\spring-exit-code-gen>java -jar build/libs/spring-exit-code-gen-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

2017-09-13 12:26:53.819  INFO 2832 --- [           main] com.scarlatti.App                        : Starting App on pc-PC with PID 2832 (C:\Users\pc\IdeaProjects\spring-exit-code-gen\build\libs\spring-exit-code-gen-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by pc in C:\Users\pc\IdeaProjects\spring-exit-code-gen\build\libs)
2017-09-13 12:26:53.824  INFO 2832 --- [           main] com.scarlatti.App                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-09-13 12:26:53.966  INFO 2832 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2752f6e2: startup date [Wed Sep 13 12:26:53 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-13 12:26:54.924  INFO 2832 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-09-13 12:26:54.962  INFO 2832 --- [           main] com.scarlatti.App                        : retrieving exit code.
2017-09-13 12:26:54.963  INFO 2832 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2752f6e2: startup date [Wed Sep 13 12:26:53 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-13 12:26:54.964  INFO 2832 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-09-13 12:26:54.969  INFO 2832 --- [           main] com.scarlatti.App                        : Started App in 1.945 seconds (JVM running for 3.132)

C:\Users\pc\IdeaProjects\spring-exit-code-gen>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

[Clone from GitHub here](https://github.com/alessandroscarlatti/spring-exit-code-gen) to try it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-exit) you need to call `System.exit` with the result of the call to `SpringApplication.exit`. Something like this:

```
@Override
void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(ctx, new ExitCodeGenerator() {
        @Override
        int getExitCode() {
            log.info 'retrieving exit code.'
            return -1
        }
    }))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Somehow that documentation page eluded me.  It makes perfect sense we have to call System.exit() with that code!  Thanks!

Comment: Using lambda: `System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context, () -> -1));`